# Does animationDidStop actually exist in WKInterfaceImage?

Tags: xcode, watchkit

In my WatchKit project I have an image and I want to execute a method as its animation started by `startAnimatingWithImagesInRange` is done. As Xcode prompts there exists an `animationDidStop` method in `WKInterfaceImage`. 
[image: Xcode prompt]
Though, I cannot find it in [WKInterfaceImage reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceImage) and this disappoints me. So, is it a bug or it is not and how do I use the method? Or should I perform some workaround using `NSTimer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

I think you found a bug in Xcode. As you noted, the documentation does not show that `WKInterfaceImage` conforms to `CAAnimation` or its delegates. Here's a little test I did in a playground to confirm that this is an issue:

```
// Documented Methods
WKInterfaceImage.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("startAnimating")) // returns true
WKInterfaceImage.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("stopAnimating")) // returns true

// Undoscumented Methods
WKInterfaceImage.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("animationDidStart:")) // returns false
WKInterfaceImage.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("animationDidStop:")) // returns false
```

So, even though it autocompletes, I don't think those methods will be hit, as WatchKit did not ship with `CAAnimation` support or an alternative to `CAAnimation`.

**Old Answer**

There is a `stopAnimation` method on `WKInterfaceImage`:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceImage/stopAnimating

Comment: I need to call some method as animation is finished and I do not need to interrupt it. So, `stopAnimation` is definitely not the solution.

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood your question. My apologies.

Comment: Taking another stab at it. Will update my answer momentarily.

Comment: And should I dig into `NSTimer` to simulate the behavior I intend to implement?

Comment: Yes, I think you could do that or use manipulate a Core Graphics context, via the example found here (http://www.raywenderlich.com/94672/watchkit-faq) under the Animation section.

Comment: I filed a bugreport with apple with some sample code in a Playground file. I mirrored it on openradar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6060429105168384